# return indexs from list of substring after matching with string

Tags: python-2.7

I have list of sub-strings , and I am checking if any of the substring is found in another string. any does return boolean.

```
>>> list=['oh' , 'mn' , 'nz' , 'ne']
>>> name='hstntxne'
>>> any(x in name for x in list)
True
>>> name='hstnzne'
>>> any(x in name for x in list)
True
```

I want to return index . for example first time it should be 3 and second time it should be 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do not call your list `list`. `list` is a python data structure and you do not want to be overriding that name unless you have a specific reason for doing so.

You can easily achieve this with a list comprehension in one line.

```
substrings = ['oh' , 'mn' , 'nz' , 'ne']
name1='hstntxne'
name2='hstnzne'

[substrings.index(x) for x in substrings if x in name1]
```

This returns 3

```
[substrings.index(x) for x in substrings if x in name2]
```

This returns [2, 3]

In order to make this work with any list of substrings, and names put it in a function:

```
def getIndex(subs, name):
    return [subs.index(x) for x in subs if x in name]

getIndex(substrings, name2) #example call
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuilt [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
def get_index(name, lis=['oh' , 'mn' , 'nz' , 'ne']):
    indx = []
    for index, element in enumerate(lis):
        if element in name:
            indx.append(index)
    return indx
```

Now `get_index(name='hstnzne')` will give `[2, 3]`

and `get_index(name='hstntxne')` will give `[3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

# Try and use regex to see if subpattern exists

l = ['oh', 'mn', 'nz', 'ne']

name='hstnzne'
match_indx = []

for i, sub_str in enumerate(l):
    result = re.split(sub_str, name)
    if (len(result)>1):
        # We could split our string due to match, so add index of substring
        match_indx.append(i)

print(match_indx)
```